# Extremely slow response in EC2 (width less than 100 requests)

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, networking

I have a EC2 instance, everything was going ok but for the last few days my website (https://www.cinescondite.com) started having a very slow response. I didn't change anything, and I have the site very well optimized. I saw that I have very high network rates, but there are so many stats that I don't know which ones really matter or which ones are affecting my site. I have a bitnami WordPress installed in my instance.

AWS Stats:
[image: AWS Stats]

Chrome console stats:
[image: Chrome console stats]

Comment: what type of instance? lack of information.

Comment: you're right, is a t2.micro.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are one of the t class instance types that use burstable credits and you ran out.  For details on [Burtsable Credits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html)  You can see this by the "CPU Credit Balance" which is the last graph.

You need to switch to fixed performance instance type or choose larger type.  If you are using a t3.large or larger try switching to an m5 in the same size.  The difference between t3.large and m5.large is only $10 a month.

If you are using a t3.medium or smaller then try stepping up to the next size.

Another way to speed up the performance is to offload content delivery with a CDN (content delivery network).  By doing thing your server will not work as hard and your user experience will be improved by the delivery speed of the CDN.

One option is to use the [W3 Total Cache Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)
And here is article on step by step instructions on using [Total Cache with AWS S3 and CDN](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-with-wordpress)

Note: I have not stepped through instructions to see if they are correct; however, in reading them they appear to be complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually have a t2.micro, with 2.000 visitors per day... maybe thats the problem, do you have some recomendation for that amount of users? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is hard to estimate.  However, if you watch to a t3.micro you get twice the amount of credits for a lower price.  And if you switch to a t3.small you'll get 4 times the amount of credits over the t2.micro for about double the cost.   I would start with one of these depending on your budget.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now i have a much better idea!

Comment: @NicolasWagner I've also added an option to move part of your workload to AWS S3 and their CDN (content delivery network).   Should improve your user experience as well.